# Should we start a 3D Printing BLOG?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Do we want to add a BLOG to this site?
Blogs are another way of communicating things that don't fit the Q&A model.

Here is a good description of [what a Blog is and how you can start one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/23/blog-overflow/).

This post on the SuperUser Blog asking for [help with their Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/09/are-you-interested-in-writing-for-our-blog/) is helpful too.

Comment: +1 - As it seems a good idea. Not sure what would go in it though - do you have any concrete examples of blog ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The description of blogs you've cited is 6 years old. Unfortunately, [blogs have since been discontinued](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow).

It is no longer possible to start a new blog.

Comment: Oh yeah... we should have checked the date! :-) Oops... that is a shame, though.

Comment: I am still researching and seeing what Stack Exchange's perspective is on this whole "xxx doesn't fit into the Q&A format and it is valid and belongs on your Blog instead ... which doesn't exist anymore ..." oops!  very inconsistent but not surprising when you get bigger and now there are silos

Comment: BTW, they have decided to keep their own blog https://stackoverflow.blog/engineering/  a bit inconsistent but no surprising either.

Answer (score 1):

+1 - As it seems a good idea. Not sure what would go in it though - do you have any concrete examples of blog ideas?

I already have a (messy) [blog](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/), and I am not sure if I could also write a blog on here too. I wonder what the score is regarding duplicating personal blogs on to SE blogs?

---

#### Content

An SE 3D print blog could be a good idea for ***Build Logs***, for example, maybe. Or maybe a page that links to other people's superlative build logs, [David Crocker's blogs](https://miscsolutions.wordpress.com/) come to mind.

Is the blog (unlike the SE Q&A site) allowed to contain ***links to cheap items/suppliers***? Apparently, reviews are allowed, from [Blog Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/23/blog-overflow/):

> **Review a product**. Reviews don’t fit the Q&A nature of the sites, but these rules don’t apply on the blog!  Between a review written by a random person on the internet and a review written by a user on the site who consistently gets a lot of upvotes, which review would you trust more?

This closed question would have fitted into a blog nicely: [What Is 3D Printing?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/what-is-3d-printing)

---

#### Concerns

So, yes, I think it would be worth starting one up and seeing how it goes... although I would be a little concerned about the regularity of posts:

> **Plan a schedule**. Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a week, posted Mondays? Will there be posts on Tuesdays and posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but you should post at least once a week.

*and*

> **Pick a posting schedule and stick to it**. It is easier to simply keep up from the get go than catch up if you fall behind.  Have a couple draft posts stashed away for a rainy day, ready to go that can be published if there is a lull.

Also, who would coordinate it? Are you putting yourself forward?

> **Have someone holding the reins**. This person doesn’t need to be the one writing all the posts, just someone that helps coordinate who is writing what and when it is getting posted.

---

However, it *is* a bit of a misfortune that Blog Overflow has a rather unfortunately acronym (as well as sounding like *Bog* Overflow).

Comment: I LIKE IT!   Thanks for stepping up and helping the frame what the content and issues would be like.  I like all the ideas regarding content.  I am sure there are a lot of people in the group that could provide reviews for the printers they have and/or build logs for the printers they build/improved.  I am wondering on how to manage/vet that.  Is there a place where people could post and vote on BLOG topics so that everything is not on you?  Ex: Post an ongoing META question "What posts would people be willing to write for the BLOG".  Some sort of an example and/or style guide would help.

Comment: @markshancock - yes, a style guide *would* be needed, I guess, for consistency's sake... although everyone has different writing styles. Maybe *this* question would suffice, w.r.t. ideas for the blog. But like I said above, getting people on board *could* be an issue. This Meta site seems to not to be terribly well frequented.