# "Best first printer" wiki/blog/closed-question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

#### TL;DR

***One thing that I did see was that the closed questions, also seem to get automatically deleted. This is a shame because some of them have interesting/informative answers. So this raises the question that whilst, yeah, close the obvious shopping answers, should the associated information/knowledge that resides in the answers be lost, or not displayed, because the question was auto-deleted? Is there a close-but-don't-delete flag?***

---

#### Preamble

*Admittedly, this is a bit of a slippery slope, and I certainly am **not** advocating that all closed questions get re-opened but I was going through [some of] the closed questions last night and it is a shame that a few were closed due to the narrow (maybe strict?) guide lines that were set initially. If I get time, I might add a new section to the meta post, [Game plan - What is on-topic?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276), for new topics pulled from some select closed questions.*

#### Beachcombing the closed question pile

I have been browsing a number of [closed questions](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes) and came across a lot of "Best first printer" type questions, which are off-topic, admittedly, but they had some good answers. I think those sorts of questions get people to want to answer, for whatever reason (pride/emotion in demonstrating their own first printer, good/bad experiences, what have you...). Maybe, instead of closing *all* of them, it is worth having just one example question, such as the example below, so that it *has already* been asked - then we can legitimately close subsequent similar duplicates, without any loss of information or help.

Taking this one as an example, https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/whats-the-least-amount-of-money-i-can-spend-to-get-a-decent-printer. It was closed as being too broad. I actually voted to close it as well, although I'm starting to wish that I hadn't. It has some great answers in it and it is a shame that they have been lost.

Since having been closed, it has now been *automatically deleted*. I'm just wondering whether it is worth undeleting it..?

I am not 100% sure whether, after undeleting it, then leaving it closed will cause it to be automatically deleted again - isn't there some sort of *closed-but-don't-delete* flag?

If there isn't then would it also have to be re-opened? Which, of course, entails other issues of "Why do we allow certain broad questions to be left open?" or "It's a shopping question!"

Regardless, it *does* seem a shame to have lost those fine (but subjective) answers.

#### Summing up

So, the point of this post is, should we save this information somewhere, and if so, in what format? I envisage a number of possibilities:

- Blog post
- [Locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)
- [Protected question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)
- [Featured tagged question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/featured/info)<sup>1</sup>   (meta only?)
- [FAQ tagged question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/info)<sup>1</sup> (meta only?)
- Closed, but not deleted, question - if this is possible
- A community wiki type post

---

<sup>1</sup> See also [Difference between FAQ and Featured tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133704/what-is-the-difference-between-the-per-site-metas-faq-and-featured-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about this in the past as well. I'd be curious if anyone from the Stack Team has any issues with the following format:

1) This functionality needs to be explicitly outlined in our On-Topic page!

2) Any of these types of questions should be created by a moderator and immediately "converted to wiki" (see mod options)

3) The question should outline an expected format for the following answers. For example, in the case of "Best Printer" questions:

```
**Make**: {Enter Manufacturer}

**Model**: {Enter Model #/Name}

**Type**: {Select tag: [FDM,SLA,SLS,DLP, etc]}

**Pros**: {Provide details of benefits}

**Cons**: {Provide details of downfalls}
```

4) Answers MUST follow the outline provided in the question or risk being deleted.

5) (Optional) Answers should be converted to wiki

Comment: Yes, I like this type of idea, especially the template. Two issues I have with blogs: they aren't that easy to find (the blog idea was floated by Markshancock last year, [Should we start a 3D Printing BLOG?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/should-we-start-a-3d-printing-blog), but nothing seemed to come of it, unfortunately - maybe due to my second issue), and; they can get overly wordy (not necessarily a bad thing but also people can get put off by the idea of having to write reams of text). Using a template means that the information will be succinct and to-the-point.

Comment: @Greenonline That's why I recommend that moderators primarily be the initiators of these types of questions, to ensure the tone is set with the template. Otherwise it becomes a s**t show of garbled information.